# Can the CosmosClient give out the number of retries that happened because of throttling (http 429)?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, throttling

I have the following code where I bulk insert a lot of items

```
var batchSize = 200;

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count() / batchSize + 1; i++)
{
    var insertOperations = new List<Task<ItemResponse<MyType>>>();

    var batchItems = items.Skip(i * batchSize).Take(batchSize);

    if (batchItems.Count() == 0)
        break;

    foreach (var batchItem in batchItems)
    {
        insertOperations.Add(container.CreateItemAsync(batchItem));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(insertOperations);
}
```

My CosmosClient is

```
CosmosClientOptions options = new CosmosClientOptions
{
    ConnectionMode = ConnectionMode.Direct,
    AllowBulkExecution = true,
    MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests = 30,
    MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)
};
```

When inserting a lot of items I seem to get throttled, as per the metrics in the Azure portal. Since I allow long wait times and a lot of retries the code will take a bit longer but it will eventually get the work done. I would be interested in logging the number of retries needed because it would help me see which operations are causing the most throttling.

Is it possible to find out how many retries the cosmos client needed to perform the operation?

Answer (score 0):

You can see them in the Diagnostics exposed as part of the operation response. Each `container.CreateItemAsync(batchItem)` returns an `ItemResponse<T>`.

The [ItemResponse](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.itemresponse-1?view=azure-dotnet).Diagnostics.ToString() contains the information for that particular operation, including any retries it might have gone through.